# Bypassing authentication on Symfony2 "welcome" page

Tags: security, symfony, url-routing

The way I'm handling authentication on my app is to put 100% of everything behind authentication, then to specify certain exceptions.

These exceptions include the login page and a few other pages. Everything is working fine except one part: the "default" page, or whatever you want to call it. I don't want people to have to log in in order to see the front page of my site, obviously, but I don't know how to make authentication not required for that.

Here's my route for my welcome page:

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: VNNPressboxBundle:User:welcome }
```

Here's my `app/config/security.yml`:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: sha1
            iterations: 1
            encode_as_base64: false
        VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha1
            iterations: 1
            encode_as_base64: false

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: VNNPressboxBundle:User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/  
            form_login: ~
            logout: ~
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/_welcome, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/new, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/create, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/thanks, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/agreement, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/welcome, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/activate, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/signup, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

The relevant part, of course, is this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/_welcome, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Even though I have things set that way, I always get booted to the login screen when I try to go to my welcome page (and by that I mean `http://myapp.com/app_dev.php` as opposed to `http://myapp.com/app_dev.php/user/welcome`). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making an exception for the default page and then setting any children behind authentication. This should put everything behind authentication except for the default page. It should also work with your exceptions.

```
- { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
```

Comment: Just that first line seemed to do it for me. Thanks! (If I used both lines, it didn't work.)